# Using localstorage from a desktop app to set values

Tags: javascript, electron

Hello I am using electron desktop app and i am using opn to open a webpage from the app. I am trying to write the data from webpage('xyz.com') onto the localstorage object and i know we do it using .setIem() function.

My doubt is,is there a way i can open the page('xyz.com') and access this localStorage variable of that page and set value for it? How can a user set a value for localStorage variable from a desktop app instance.

For example, say i open the page 'xyz.com' and set variable name localStorage.setItem('name','Dhirish');
Now i move to the desktop app and i need to access this 'name' variable and change it to my desired variable.

Is there a way to access it and change it? Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

No, localStorage is [specific to the origin of the document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). This is like asking if scripts from Facebook.com can access the localStorage of Google.com.

> The read-only localStorage property allows you to access a Storage object for the Document's **origin**

Comment: Ok Nick, Can i send some data,say blob data to a particular webpage and upload it via code just plain javascript code?